# Moving log files & data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, percona

Is it possible to separate out data files and log files of MySQL from one drive to another?

For eg:

Data (actual database data and system tablespace ibdata) in one partition, say /data and log files (ibdata0 and ibdata1 only) in one partition, say /redo?

Is it possible? I know the binary logs can be moved to a different partition but I have the doubt for above scenario.

I'm using Percona Server 5.6 on linux.

Edit:

Just checked out, If I set innodb_log_group_home_dir to a different location, would it work?

Comment: Note.  This concept is a good idea only in certain situations.  The most common case where it is likely to be useful:  SSD for data & spinning drive for logs.  If all your drives are 'equal', it is _better to use RAID striping_.

Comment: That's there but I'm moving it out of default because I do not want it to be in root partition

Comment: Yes, it is good to keep everything you can out of the root partition.  Usually it is too small to survive a few upgrades.

Comment: @RickJames few upgrades? Rick can you elaborate on that?

Comment: OS upgrades (and other things that insist on being in the root partition) need room to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using innodb_log_group_home_dir will put your ib_logfile* on the specified location. You can also opt to do the following:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/iblog
innodb_data_home_dir=/ibdata
```

So the system tablespace (ibdata1) goes inside /ibdatafiles folder, while the redo log files (ib_logfile*) goes inside /iblogfiles.

```
# ls -l /ibdata
total 12296
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Jul 17 08:59 ibdata1
# ls -l /iblog
total 98320
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jul 17 08:59 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jul 17 08:59 ib_logfile1
# ls -l /var/lib/mysql
total 48
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  56 Jul 17 08:59 auto.cnf
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   5 Jul 17 08:59 centos1.pid
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql   0 Jul 17 08:59 mysql
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 151 Jul 17 08:59 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  19 Jul 17 08:59 mysql-bin.index
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   0 Jul 17 08:59 mysql.sock
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql   0 Jul 17 08:59 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql   0 Jul 17 08:59 test
```

Comment: ok in this case if I mention the above two variables, where will the databases be stored at? in data-dir?

Comment: @tesla747 databases will be stored inside the datadir path in this case /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Ok If I just mention the datadir and not the innodb_data_home_dir then both databases and system tablespace goes into the path mentioned by the datadir correct?

Comment: @tesla747 yes, the default value for innodb_data_home_dir is MySQL's data directory